# return undifined instead of rendering html tag

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

i have a component

```
 import React from 'react'

export default function FilterRow (props){
 return (
   <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
     <label className="label-filter text-capitalize" htmlFor={props.id}>{props.text}</label>
     <button id={props.id} className="btn-filter" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target={props.target}
      name={props.name}  onClick={props.buttonHandler}>
       { props.btnValue ?  "-"  :  "+" } 
     </button>
   </div>
  )
}
```

and parent component that passing props and fuction to this component
fuction:

```
  handleButtonStates = (event , prevState) => {
    const { name  } = event.target
    console.log("hi from" , name );
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {[name] : !prevState[name]}
    })
  }
```

usage in parent component:

```
<FilterRow  id="sort-btn" text="sort by" btnValue={this.state.sortBtn}
                            buttonHandler={this.handleButtonStates} target="#collapseSort" name="sortBtn"/>
```

when i use this function to conditional render - and + it works fine
but when i change - and + on fas icons or any other html tag like this

```
{ props.btnValue ?  <label>y</label>  :  <label>no</label> }
```

function start to return undefined instead of button name , why is this working like that and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Some typos in your code:

```
Labe => label and <Label => <Label>
```